# Fluid Powered TYPO3 FLUX Fluidcontent - No Output in Frontend?

Tags: output, typo3, frontend, fluid, flux

I've made a TYPO3-Installation 6.2.9 with [Fluid powered TYPO3](https://fluidtypo3.org/) - the first steps with the Pre-configured Distribution "[Site](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/site)" were fine. My Site/Page-Template is installed and I added all the TypoScript stuff.

Now I want to use FLUIDCONTENT (FCE) with FLUX. I've added a new Template-File `TeaserOne.html` and I try to use the Layout from the Distribution `Content.html`.

**Now I can see and write into my input-fields in Backend, but I've no Output in Frontend?! What else do I need?**

I only see the Content-Element Headline. Not the FLEXform.
I'm using the latest Versions of `flux (7.1.2)`, `fluidpages (3.1.2)`, `fluidcontent (4.1.1)`, `fluid_core (1.0.2)` and `vhs (2.1.4)`.
The static template "fluidcontent_core" was included via pre-configured Distribution.

*myext/Resources/Private/Templates/TeaserOne.html*

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
     xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
     f:schemaLocation="https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/fluid-master.xsd"
     xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers"
     flux:schemaLocation="https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/flux-master.xsd">

    <f:layout name="Content" />

    <f:section name="Configuration">

        <flux:form id="fluidcontenttest" options="{icon: 'Icons/Content/Hello.gif', group: 'New Elements'}">

            <flux:field.text name="teasertext" label="hier lorem eintragen" rows="5" cols="30" required="FALSE" />

        </flux:form>

    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Preview">

        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="30%">Ausgabe:</td>
                <td width="70%">
                    <f:format.crop maxCharacters="100">{teasertext}</f:format.crop>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Main">
        <h3>TEST: I am a content element! But no Output?</h3>
        <p> {teasertext} </p>
    </f:section>
</div>
```

*myext/Resources/Private/Layouts/Content.html*

```
<f:layout name="Content" />
<f:render section="Main" />
```

[image: Backend]

[image: File structure]

[image: typoscript]

Comment: Seems like the tt_content.fluidcontent rendering is missing. Did you include the fluidcontent_core static in your root page (TYPO3 backend)?

Comment: Hi,  yes the static template "fluidcontent_core" was included via pre-configured Distribution.  I try to use "fluidbootstraptheme" but I have def. no Frontend Output. There must be sth wrong with my installation?

Comment: Can you give me a screenshot of the TS setup tt_content

Comment: Oho! I don't have a 'tt_content TypoScript Setup' at these Blank TYPO3-Installation. The standard Content Elements will be shown. What do I need in this case? I'm sorry!

Comment: I followed that Screencast from Claus Due: http://vimeo.com/110469200 - Have I forget something?

Comment: I meant a screenshot from the TYPO3 Object Browser :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70402/discussion-between-christoph-and-user2310852).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the frontend rendering configuration for the CType fluidcontent_content is missing. Did you add the following to your typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['contentRenderingTemplates'] = array('fluidcontentcore/Configuration/TypoScript/');
```